# Spring Expression Language- Is it possible to use #this in SEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a base class where i am annotating method with

```
@kafkaListener(topics=#{beanName.topicName}).
```

Every subclass extending a base class could have a unique topicName on which they will be listening to.

Every subclass is a registered bean.

Now what i want to do is, have the method annotated with kafkaListener in the baseClass, I dont want to move it the subClass.
The bean names are going to be different for every subclass .
So is there anyway i can make the assignment of

```
topics=#{beanName.topicName}
```

generalised?

I have tried #{this.topicName} but that does not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `#{#this.topicName}` ?
I can't check by myself, but i am quite sure that the syntax to refer to the _this variable_ is `#this`

Comment: `#this` doesn't refer to the current bean `The variable #this is always defined and refers to the current evaluation object (against which unqualified references are resolved).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>A reference to the current bean or bean name is not available to the SpEL evaluation.</strike>

[Pull Request issued](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/534).

Comment: any plans to add this feature in future releases?

Comment: I found a fairly easy way to do it; [pull request here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/534).

Comment: appreciate it gary.

Comment: Will this be part of any future release? Wanted to use it in production.

Comment: It will be in 2.1.2. We just released 2.1.1 so no immediate plans, probably a few weeks, but we could do it sooner; when do you need it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In 1 week.

Comment: It’s not like we can’t go ahead with the release without it but would appreciate if it’s possible to use it.

Comment: We have a bunch of other releases to do next Monday; I'll plan to do it then.